# How register is encoded in an ARM64 mov instruction?

Tags: assembly, arm64, machine-code

I would like to understand  which bit, in a ARM64 mov instruction, are responsible for the register information. I compile my code using clang, targeting aarch64 architecture.

For example, i obtain this instruction with the following machine code:

```
01418C52 MOVZ            W1, #0x6208
```

Looking at the documentation "Arm Architecture Reference Manual Armv8, for Armv8-A architecture profile" page C6-1123
[image]

Rd is the field holding the register information as specify in the documentation :

*Is the 32-bit name of the general-purpose destination register, encoded in the "Rd" field.*
 *Is the 64-bit name of the general-purpose destination register, encoded in the "Rd" field.*

Using the website [armconverter](https://armconverter.com), i change the value of the register.

I obtain the following code as expected :

```
02418C52 MOVZ            W2, #0x6208
```

The hexadecimal value from the left (least significant) changes from 0x01 to 0x02.
It seems that the code is little-endian but the documentation is big-endian. But if i change the letter of the register from W to X, another bit is shifted.

```
02418CD2 MOVZ            X2, #0x6208
```

The last value at the right is changed from 0xC52 to 0xCD2. Why ?

```
>>> bin(0xCD2)
'0b110011010010'
>>> bin(0xC52)
'0b110001010010'
```

From the documentation it is the most significant bit from the field *sf* who are responsible for the selection of the register based on the size of the immediate value (32b or 64b).

```
32-bit (sf == 0)

MOVZ <Wd>, #<imm>{, LSL #<shift>}
64-bit (sf == 1)

MOVZ <Xd>, #<imm>{, LSL #<shift>}
```

But the bit is not at the right location. Perhaps i'm using the wrong documentation. I would like to understand which field in the 32 bits instruction are responsible for the register value.

Thanks

Comment: _"The last value at the left is changed from 0xC52 to 0xCD2. Why ?"_ You should look at the bytes. The relevant byte is the one that changed from 0x52 to 0xD2, i.e. its most significant bit (which is `sf`) changed from off to on.

Comment: However, I would've expected `528C4101` to be shown in little-endian mode, so I found that conversion tool a bit confusing.

Comment: It is. It's just that that conversion tool by default shows the bytes with the most-significant byte to the right (01,41,8C,52 <-- this byte).

Comment: Thanks i understand my mistake now ! :)

Comment: looks like you should stop using armconverter...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following up to prior comments and answers

The sf bit is never at bit 7 it is always at bit 31 for this instruction, the ARM view from the document you posted is the only proper way to view the instruction.  Never try to byte swap that view of the instruction.  Fix the data or even better use a tool that works rather than a buggy/broken one.

so.s

```
movz w1,#0x6208
```

gnu binutils

```
aarch64-none-elf-as so.s -o so.o
aarch64-none-elf-objdump -d so.o

so.o:     file format elf64-littleaarch64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <.text>:
   0:   528c4101    mov w1, #0x6208
```

clang/llvm

```
clang -c so.s -o so.o
llvm.objdump so.o
    
Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <$x.0>:
    0: 01 41 8c 52      mov w1, #25096
```

now this is different than 01418c52, the spacing implies these are bytes not a whole word and then that can indicate there may be some endianness involved.  I do not agree necessarily that disassemblers byte swap, they may as in this case show a byte view vs a word or halfword view yes.  And then if a halfword view you have to know what order they show in memory/to the processor:

```
mov.w r10,r11

0:  ea4f 0a0b   mov.w   r10, r11
```

0xEA4F is the first half of the instruction in this case.

Both clang/llvm and binutils use the same file format as shown so you can disassemble the clang/llvm generated binary with binutils

```
aarch64-none-elf-objdump -d so.o
Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <.text>:
    0:  528c4101    mov w1, #0x6208                 // #25096
```

There are different forms of big endian.  As documented for armv8

If I have the 32 bit little endian (default/normal) word 0x11223344 at address 0x1000 then little endian the BYTES view is

```
0x1000: 0x44
0x1001: 0x33
0x1002: 0x22
0x1000: 0x11
```

(not 11223344 that is a word view)

for big endian the BYTE view of the same data at the same time is

```
0x1000: 0x44
0x1001: 0x33
0x1002: 0x22
0x1000: 0x11
```

Which is the same, known as byte invariant or BE-8.  For armv6 and later big endian is BE-8, byte invariant. (ARMv4 and v5 are word invariant BE-32)

A word access though does vary as one would expect:

```
0x1000: 0x11223344 little endian DATA
0x1000: 0x44332211 big endian DATA
0x1000: 0x11223344 little endian INSTRUCTION fetch
0x1000: 0x11223344 big endian INSTRUCTION fetch
```

> Instruction endianness

> In ARMv8-A, A64 instructions have a fixed length of 32 bits and are always little-endian.

The tool you are using is simply broken and if the goal of the tool is to assemble and show you the machine code or vice versa, and it cannot do this simple task (which it clearly cannot), then I would simply avoid the site as a whole.  If they cannot do something this simple then they do not understand the instruction set well enough.  Their "gdb" big endian switch is not a solution it is just one more thing that is broken.

The ARM documentation is correct and binutils is easy to use.  clang/llvm a little harder, I can provide a build script if you want.  Although binutils objdump has its issues it is still the best set of tools for this kind of work.  You can
easily go back and forth from assembly language and machine code.

```
movz w1,#0x6208
.inst 0x528c4101

aarch64-none-elf-as so.s -o so.o
aarch64-none-elf-objdump -d so.o
so.o:     file format elf64-littleaarch64

Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <.text>:
   0:   528c4101    mov w1, #0x6208                 // #25096
   4:   528c4101    mov w1, #0x6208                 // #25096
```

(can as well with clang/llvm)

```
Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <$x.0>:
       0: 01 41 8c 52   mov w1, #25096
       4: 01 41 8c 52   mov w1, #25096
```

You can see from the document segment you posted the instruction starts with x1010010 which can either be 0x52 or 0xD2 the (broken) tool shows 02418C52 which quickly indicates they may have byte swapped the machine code (further investigation is required if you see such a thing as it could be dumb luck) if you had not see a 0x52 nor 0xD2 in the data then it is not the same instruction, or there is some other issue.

If you want to see the machine code for this architecture just use binutils or clang/llvm or some other easy to use, not-broken, tool.

Comment: thanks @old_timer. I will be careful with the tool i used and do some tests with clang/llvm, objdump and binutils.

Answer (score 4):

Your confusion comes down entirely to endianness.

From [the manual](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0487/latest):

```
B2.6.2      Instruction endianness

                In Armv8-A, A64 instructions have a fixed length
                of 32 bits and are always little-endian.
```

Disassemblers, on the other hand, have a habit of showing raw bytes - for A64 that is a rather unfortunate choice, but I would assume it stems from the handling of variable-length instruction sets like x86(_64) and ARM/Thumb, where this does make sense.

But in short, when your disassembler shows `01418C52` then those are raw bytes and should be read as `0x528c4101`.
Or displayed graphically:

```
+------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| Byte |    01    |    41    |    8C    |    52    |
+------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| Bits | 00000001 | 01000001 | 10001100 | 01010010 |
+------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
                ^                         ^
                |                         |
Least significant bit           Most significant bit
```

That's really just how little-endian works.

Comment: Thanks, i understand now ! I did my homework with python to place the sf flag in the little-endian instruction. I will put my output in a edit. Thanks again i appreciate your help.

Comment: GNU and LLVM tools get this right:  `aarch64-linux-gnu-objdump -d` shows `528c4102`, the 32-bit interpretation.  llvm-objdump -d shows `02 41 8c 52`, the raw byte sequent.  Both of those are equivalent and not misleading; don't blame disassemblers, just https://armconverter.com/ which stupidly grouped it up into `02418C52`.  The GDB/LLDB toggle fixes it to `528C4102` which it calls "big endian".  But it's not a "big endian" byte sequence, there are no spaces so it's the 32-bit integer value.  Anyway, @overtur, you should accept this answer by clicking the checkmark under the vote arrows.

Answer (score 2):

GNU and LLVM tools get this right:  `aarch64-linux-gnu-objdump -d` shows `528c4102`, the 32-bit integer interpretation of the 4 bytes.  llvm-objdump -d shows `02 41 8c 52`, the raw byte sequence.  Both of those are equivalent and not misleading.

But https://armconverter.com/ stupidly groups it up into `02418C52` (in its default "GDB" mode).  This is bad.  If you wanted to manually encode some AArch64 shellcode, you'd use `.long 0x528c4102` (on a little-endian assembler targeting e.g. like x86, AArch64, or whatever) to get a representation of `MOVZ  W2, #0x6208`.

**By convention, a single string of digits without spaces has place-values that increase from right to left, and represent a single integer value of some width.**  It's not you, it's https://armconverter.com/ that's the problem.

armconverter has a "GDB/LLDB" toggle that fixes it to `528C4102` in LLDB mode, which it calls "big endian".  But it's not a "big endian" byte sequence, there are no spaces so it's the 32-bit integer value.  `02418C52` is the integer you'd get if you interpret the 4 bytes as big-endian (opposite of what an AArch64 CPU does), `528C4102` is the correct little-endian interpretation of those 4 bytes.

**I think armconverter is using "big endian" to actually mean "byte reverse before removing spaces between bytes".  This is braindead misuse of terminology.**  Again, both GNU binutils and LLVM disassemblers get this right, the problem is purely armconverter.

Comment: Thanks a lot @PeterCordes